# System fan cutting on and off in heat mode any ideas?

Tags: hvac

Its a 30 some year old unit, but didn't have this problem till recent the model is Tempstar PGAA24D1K1. What is happening is the system will cut on heat the fan will kick in a run for some time, this can be any where between 1-3 mins before it starts the whole start then stop which will happen every 10-20 sec and will keep doing that for 1-4 mins after the cycle is over. I need an idea what is going on any help would be great because its not been a good year with techs touching it, and just so its answered its a gas unit.

Comment: Knowing the model is good. Knowing the brand would be excellent! You can [edit] that into your question (so everyone will find it quickly). Also, while you're in there, some punctuation and formatting would help us better understand so we can better help you. You might want to indicate what kind of time frame "run for some time" is, because most HVAC systems work that way - they turn on, heat or cool for "some time", then shut off. To me this sounds perfectly normal so far...

Comment: The furnace in my old house had a period when the blower would turn off and on while the heat was going. Sometimes it would turn off long enough that the furnace would trigger the overheat and turn off. The behavior wasn't what the furnace blower had been doing before: staying on all the time heat was called for. The relay turning the blower on was bad. A new relay fixed it.